# AngularJS format value in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to know if there is any way to solve my problem below without replacing `\n` by other values:

The user can enter a description for something in a textarea. He is also able to make line-breaks in that textarea.

In my controller there is a `description` value which contains the input string like `This is my \n description with a line break`.

This value will be saved into the database after the user submitted it.

**My problem is:**

if the user wants to edit his description the value in the textarea should be auto-formatted, so it should look like when he entered the description.

**First**: are there any special tricks to format a textarea where the input comes from angularjs ?
**Second**: is there any way to keep the `\n` in the text but display it as a line break?

Answer (score 0):

New lines inside a textarea are new lines in the resulting string (`\n`).

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEBYu/202/) demonstrates such behaviour.

If you want to store `\n` in the database, there is nothing to do, the string is already of that format.

If by 'linebreak', you mean the `<br>` tag and you actually meant that the string comes from the DB containing such tags, then you should replace them beforehand I suppose.

Ideally your database should contain newlines (`\n`), you should save and fetch newlines from it as is, no conversion.

you can also make your custom filter which will replace `\n` to `<br>`

```
// filters js
myApp.filter("nl2br", function($filter) {
 return function(data) {
   if (!data) return data;
   return data.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
 };
});`
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! 
is there any way that the textarea can actually display a \n ? or do i have to convert it into a <br> to display it properly ?

Comment: Why you want to show \n into textarea? and if you want to show then you can convert \n to <br>.

Comment: oh sry i meant i dont want to display the \n it should be a <br>
so there is no way i can avoid converting it into a <br> ?